# Identity Server 4 CORS not configured

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have put my IS4 on a server and lets call it http://test.myis4.com. Now I am trying to login with an angular application against it, however I keep getting blocked by CORS. The angular client is being served with an MVC Core application and it runs on http://localhost:5002 port. I have tried to do this from my localhost by running it on that port.

On the IS4 server I have tried adding on the client the following:

```
new Client {
    // code is omitted
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>() { "http://localhost:5002" }
}
```

With the above I still get the CORS error, then I have tried adding it to the services direclty:

```
var cors = new DefaultCorsPolicyService(null)
{
    AllowedOrigins = { "http://localhost:5002" }
};
services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>(cors);
services.AddIdentityServer()
//rest omitted
```

The above still gave me the same CORS error, my last attempt was to add it through application builder as such:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5002").AllowAnyHeader());
app.UseIdentityServer();
//rest omitted
```

With this last attempt it still did not work. I'm not quire sure what I'm doing wrong at this point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

On the second code block, that you've shown - you need to first `AddIdentityServer()` and then add the Cors Policy service and you can also do it straight after adding Identity server to the services. Something like:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            // .. if you need something in general (can go without the options)
        })
        .AddCorsPolicyService<YOUR_IMPLEMENTATION_OF_ICorsPolicyService>()
        // rest omitted
```

This is because the `AddIdentitiyServer()` overwrites the adding of the CORS service - [Code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/63a50d7838af25896fbf836ea4e4f37b5e179cd8/src/Configuration/DependencyInjection/BuilderExtensions/Core.cs#L136).

Comment: Ok, what's the difference with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58960907/216652 ? Which one is better - adding  AddCorsPolicyService() or adding AddCors() along with UseCors() ?